# Is there a way to always launch the launcher activity after app was killed by system?

Tags: android, performance, android-activity

When I test my app on Android 8.1.0, I found a system behavior:
1. Open my app. Follow this path to open `Activity B`: `LauncherActivity` -> `Activity A` -> `Activity B`.
2. Press Home button, and go to app's permission page.
3. Revoke a permission.
4. Back to app through task list, and app crashes.

Actually, in Step 3, as soon as user revokes a permission, Android system kills the app process immediately. So when user reopen the app, the system will launch the top activity in the stack. In this case, it is `Activity B`. `Activity B` will call its `onCreate(savedInstanceState)` method with a non-null bundle, which is saved before the app process was killed. The other activities in the stack(`LauncherActivity`, `Activity A`) will not be instantiated, unless `Activity B` finish itself without starting other new activity, e.g. user just presses Back button.

Here is the problem, many foundational modules are initialized in `Application` and `LauncherActivity`. But in the above situation, when user reopen app, Android system will relaunch `Activity B` directly without launching `LauncherActivity`. This will cause `Activity B` crashes.

I have to initialize some foundational modules in `LauncherActivity`,  not `Application`. So, Is there a way to always launch the launcher activity after app was killed by system?

Comment: Your app is not killed by the system.It's the activity B in onPause mode .so if you revoke a permission from settings then its your activity B which must handle the permission. Do not write all the permissions in launcher activity.As per activities requirement ask permission per activity so that your app will not crash

Comment: App is killed by the system. When I revoke any one of the granted permissions(before I reopen my app), even this permission is not needed by `Activity B`, I can find my app's process was killed, by the result of `adb shell ps -A | greps [app's package name]`. @userI